# Recreating jQuery's selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to recreate jQuery's id and classname selectors. Here's what I have so far:

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

If I have an element`<div id="fire">Fire</div>`, then I can call for it with:

```
$('fire').style.fontSize = '36px';
```

This works brilliantly, however, I want to extend this to use id and classname with `#` and `.` respectively. What I've attempted does not work:

http://jsfiddle.net/6t58Lc7v/

Comment: Ok, what about looking at jQuery's source-code?

Comment: Any reason to recreate? Recreating a generic selector is much complicated. You can always go with sizzle (http://sizzlejs.com/) if you don't want jQuery.

Comment: jQuery's [`$` function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js#L16) is far more versatile than this. It's a small module; reading through it will likely give you a much deeper appreciation for what it's prepared to handle. Understand too that you could build your implementation on top of `document.querySelectorAll` and accept a direct selector.

Comment: @Vega, I'd like to use this for personal projects where I don't need an entire framework.

Comment: @OP That is why I recommended `sizzle`, but then you don't need it if it is small project with limited use. Check out `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` for easy selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example in your fiddle doesn't work because it's looking for an element with the ID of "#fire" (with the # character).  You need to omit this character:

```
function $(id) {
    if (id.indexOf('#') == 0) {
        return document.getElementById(id.substring(1));
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6t58Lc7v/1/